Error while opening source report from Dashboard component: [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dataType')]
An user of our org is getting this error while opening a source report from the Dahsboard component in Salesforce: This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
[Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dataType')]

I have confirmed that the user has access to the source report folder, and doesn't present any error while opening the report separately. This only happens when he clicks on the 'View Report' link under the Dashboard component.
Any idea of what could be the issue?

I had the same problem and after verify all the points of this doc: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385222&type=1 I still have the problem.
I realized that the dashboard was dynamic:

I've cloned the dashboard
I've tried access the report data with the affected user.
Then, I've set it again as dynamic.
The issue is solved.

I think it was matter of clone the dashboard.
